# C#: How to fix Model Mismatch error: ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, automapper

How can I fix Model Mismatch error? I get this exception error `An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request. ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type`.

I have three actions for the Index, Detail and Edit pages in my controller, when i navigate from edit to Detail and Index to Detail page, i get Model Mismatch error. Need your help on how to fix or map between them.

```
Task<IList<VW_ProductDTO>> GetProducts();
Task<ProductDTO> GetProductsbyId(int id);
```

I have mapping as:

```
 CreateMap<Product, ProductDTO>();       
 CreateMap<VW_Product, VW_ProductDTO>();
 CreateMap<ProductDTO, Product>()
```

And In my controller i have the following Actions:

For Index.cshtml:  uses VW_ProductDTO

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetProducts([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var Products = await ProductService.GetProducts();

        return Json(Products.ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }
```

For Detail.cshtml

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int id)
    {
        var Product = await ProductService.GetProductsbyId(id);
        return View(Product);
    }
```

For Edit.cshtml

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id)
    {  
      var Product = await ProductService.GetProductsbyId(id);
       return View(Product);
    }
```

and In my view a have a link  to navigate to the detail page

```
<a asp-controller="Product" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@Model.ID">View Product</a>
```

when i click on the link to view the detail page i get this error

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the
>   ViewDataDictionary is of type 'ProductDTO', but this
>   ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type
>   'VW_ProductDTO'.

Comment: Your `GetProductsbyId` return data should be `VW_ProductDTO` instead of `ProductDTO`.Or you could change your Details view to `@model ProductDTO`.

Comment: @Rena understood here is my problem `VW_ProductDTO` is using a sql view ProductDTO is a table  and i have to do that way

Comment: @user7983964 Then you will have to instantiate the expected class from the one you get from the db, or change your viewmodel class to VW_ProductDTO instead